# Use complex type in schema extension

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to extend an existing schema to add a complex type to an existing complex type. Is this possible? I've tried the code below, but it isn't valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Types -->
    <xs:complexType name="plotType">     
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bufferSize"   type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Base Schema w/ connection restrictions -->
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="baseConfig.xsd">
        <xs:simpleType name="connectionName">
            <xs:restriction base="connectionName">
                <xs:pattern value="test"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>    

        <!-- Additional default values -->
        <xs:complexType name="baseGuiConfigType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="baseGuiConfigType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="plot" type="plotType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Don't tell us it fails. Tell us how it fails.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm really not as worried about the specific failure as the yes/no part of the question, which is whether it is even possible to extend a type with another user defined complexType or not. I've only been able to find examples using built-in types.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to derive one complex type from another by extension.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks! Sometimes knowing a problem is solvable is the key to solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as Michael Kay noted, it is possible to extend the schema with complexTypes in addition to built-in types.

The problem is that `plotType` must be defined after the `redefine` block. Refactoring the code as such fixes the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="baseConfig.xsd">
        <xs:simpleType name="connectionName">
            <xs:restriction base="connectionName">
                <xs:pattern value="test"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>    

        <!-- Additional default values -->
        <xs:complexType name="baseGuiConfigType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="baseGuiConfigType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="plot" type="plotType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>

    <!-- Types -->
    <xs:complexType name="plotType">     
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bufferSize"   type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```